Tokyo-type pitch accent
Why is tokyo-type accent pattern so much scattered, but discontinuously, throughout Japan, from western Japan and even reaching such eastern regions as Chugoku, northeastern Kyushu etc.? It is a long time situation which, in my opinion, cannot be accounted for,  just considering modern socio-linguistic influences. Is it a long time penetration of Tokyo Japanese or  is it dependent on an original kinship of the relevant dialects to the Tokyo one. And why such distribution?

I guess you need to distinguish between "Tokyo('s) accent" and "Tokyo-type accent". The latter which linguists talk about is "accent system that only downstep position is meaningful in a word". Each dialect has its own pitch pattern and classification that don't always conform to Tokyo's.

Shibatani's The Languages of Japan talks some about the phenomenon where a "prestige" center for a speech community (such as the imperial court, centered on Kyōto) is more likely to invent neologisms, which then gradually spread out to the provinces (if at all).  I don't recall if he talks about pitch patterns the same way, but this seems like it might be a similar development, suggesting that the "Tokyo-type" might be an older stratum.

After posting my question, I have found an intersting research on the matter by a Dutch scholar,Elisabeth de Boer.
Indeed and not surprisingly, the peculiar distribution of the accent-types in Japan had aroused the interest of linguistics for a quite a while.
I have read that two theories have been proposed to explain the evolution of the pitch system and the consequent territorial pattern:
The ”traditional theory”
The “Ramsey’s theory”
I am not a linguist so  I am skipping the very interesting arguments she has put forwards, pro and contra, either one .
I am rather intrested on the implications in terms of distribution.
The Ramsey ‘s theory set the Tokyo type accent as the closest to the original old japanese one and the Kansai zone as a centre of innovation.
This explains why we find a sort of an island around Osaka and Kobe, which is the the mere extent of the innovation widespreading. Outside that island, persists, both eastwards and westwards, the large are of the Tokyo type accent, which should be better considered as a pristine accent-type. Maybe, however, that the historical and sociopolitical importance of Tokyo had slowed down and eventually stopped the the progression of the kansai type accent throughout Japan ??
